# Mininum font size "12" in Firefox (>3.6.12) - default setting?

Tags: firefox, browser, fonts, web-development, ubuntu-10.10

I'm designing a new webpage and saw that Firefox has set a minimum font size of 12.

Is this just a misconfiguration of my own browser, or is this really a default setting of Firefox? In the latter case, it would affect my design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, you can adjust it:

> Setting a minimum font size
>
> Some web sites may display text which
>   is too small to read comfortably. To
>   make such pages easier to read, you
>   can set a minimum font size. On web
>   pages that try to display text smaller
>   than this size, Firefox will enlarge
>   the text to your chosen size.
>
> To set a minimum font size, go to
>   Tools/Options (or Preferences on Mac)
>   and select the "Content" panel. In the
>   "Fonts & Colors" section, immediately
>   after the default font and size
>   selection, click the "Advanced"
>   button. You can specify a minimum font
>   size from the dropdown menu.
>
> Note that some web pages may display
>   incorrectly depending on your choice
>   of a minimum font size.

Source: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility_features_of_Firefox (scroll down partway to the `Setting Minimum Font Size` header)

On my Windows machine, I can set this size as low as 9 points...hope that helps!

I installed Ubuntu 10.10 in a virtual machine, and Firefox was already preinstalled - the default font was Serif, and the default font size was 16, the minimum 9. The default on my Windows system is 16 also. FWIW...

Comment: I know that I can changed that, but my question was if a size of 12 is a default setting in a Firefox standard installation? If yes, I have to reconsider my design.

Comment: @Bevor - let me try a fresh install of Firefox, and see what the default font size is...

Comment: Thanks. Could you please post it as answer. Otherwise I can't check it answered.